# Make BeautifulSoup handle line breaks as a browser would

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, line-breaks

I'm using BeautifulSoup (version '4.3.2' with Python 3.4) to convert html documents to text.  The problem I'm having is that sometimes web pages have newline characters "\n" that wouldn't actually get rendered as a new line in a browser, but when BeautifulSoup converts them to text, it leaves in the "\n".

Example:

Your browser probably renders the following all in one line (even though have a newline character in the middle):

This is a
paragraph.

And your browser probably renders the following in multiple lines even though I'm entering it with no newlines:

This is a paragraph.

This is another paragraph.

But when BeautifulSoup converts the same strings to text, the only line line breaks it uses are the newline literals - and it always uses them:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

doc = "<p>This is a\nparagraph.</p>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc)

soup.text
Out[181]: 'This is a \n paragraph.'

doc = "<p>This is a paragraph.</p><p>This is another paragraph.</p>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc)

soup.text
Out[187]: 'This is a paragraph.This is another paragraph.'
```

Does anyone know how to make BeautifulSoup extract text in a more beautiful way (or really just get all the newlines correct)?  Are there any other simple ways around the problem?

Answer (score 33):

`get_text` might be helpful here:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> doc = "<p>This is a paragraph.</p><p>This is another paragraph.</p>"
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(doc)
>>> soup.get_text(separator="\n")
u'This is a paragraph.\nThis is another paragraph.'
```

Comment: This suggestion works for the `<p>` tag example but does not work in general. For example: `<p>This is some text <font style="white-space:nowrap">which cannot be wrapped</font> to a new line.</p>` will be rendered in a browser on one line but using `get_text('\n')` will add a new line char where the OP does NOT want one.

Comment: This isn't suitable at all - it will put a line break at the end of every block of text regardless of whether it's a line-breaking element. <p>some <i>italic</i> text</p> becomes three lines.

Answer (score 8):

While I do realize this is an old post, I wanted to highlight some behavior in bs4 in the way text is printed from tags.

I'm not an html expert but these are the few things I considered while trying to make bs4 print text as a browser would -

The behaviors I'm about to describe are applicable to `tag.get_text()` and `tag.find_all(text=True,recursive=True)` functionalities in BeautifulSoup

1. **New Lines in the HTML Source**

Beautiful soup prints a new line if it is available in the html source

2. **Implicit new lines due to block level elements**

Beautiful soup does not add new lines before and after block elements like `p` if there are no source new lines around the tag

3. **`<br>` tags**

BeautifulSoup does not print a new line if the source contains a `<br>` tag and there are no source new lines around the `<br>` tag

**Solution**

Here is a solution that works for many cases (the limiting factor being -1)The list of all inline elements 2) How CSS/JS might affect the inline-ness or block-ness at runtime in a browser environment

```py
def get_text(tag: bs4.Tag) -> str:
    _inline_elements = {"a","span","em","strong","u","i","font","mark","label",
    "s","sub","sup","tt","bdo","button","cite","del","b","a","font",}

    def _get_text(tag: bs4.Tag) -> typing.Generator:
        for child in tag.children:
            if isinstance(child, bs4.Tag):
                # if the tag is a block type tag then yield new lines before after
                is_block_element = child.name not in _inline_elements
                if is_block_element:
                    yield "\n"
                yield from ["\n"] if child.name == "br" else _get_text(child)
                if is_block_element:
                    yield "\n"
            elif isinstance(child, bs4.NavigableString):
                yield child.string

    return "".join(_get_text(tag))
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up lifting the [list of inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements#list_of_inline_elements) from Mozilla and using this to parse all the elements in the markup, add `\n`'s accordingly.

- Strip out any unwanted tags such as `<style>`, `<script>` and
  `<code>`.
- Take `<br>` out of the list as it is a line-breaking element, which I
  give a single `\n`, everything else not in the list gets a `\n\n`.

```py
NON_BREAKING_ELEMENTS = ['a', 'abbr', 'acronym', 'audio', 'b', 'bdi', 'bdo', 'big', 'button', 
    'canvas', 'cite', 'code', 'data', 'datalist', 'del', 'dfn', 'em', 'embed', 'i', 'iframe', 
    'img', 'input', 'ins', 'kbd', 'label', 'map', 'mark', 'meter', 'noscript', 'object', 'output', 
    'picture', 'progress', 'q', 'ruby', 's', 'samp', 'script', 'select', 'slot', 'small', 'span', 
    'strong', 'sub', 'sup', 'svg', 'template', 'textarea', 'time', 'u', 'tt', 'var', 'video', 'wbr']

def html_to_text(markup, preserve_new_lines=True, strip_tags=['style', 'script', 'code']):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(unescape(markup), "html.parser")
    for element in soup(strip_tags): element.extract()
    if preserve_new_lines:
        for element in soup.find_all():
            if element.name not in NON_BREAKING_ELEMENTS:
                element.append('\n') if element.name == 'br' else element.append('\n\n')
    return soup.get_text(" ")
```